# How flutter_riverpod listens to a list

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I want to use flutter_riverpod to watch a list of data. But when I change the data content in the list, the widget is not refreshed.

flutter_riverpod: ^1.0.0-dev.7

Part of the code is as follows：

```dart
final personProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => PersonProvider());

class PersonProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Person> personList;

  PersonProvider() {
    personList = [
      Person(name: "jack", age: 20),
      Person(name: "rose", age: 18),
    ];
  }
  
  void changeData() {
    // change person
    //personList[0].name = "new jack";
    // add person
    personList.add(Person(name: "lili", age: 25));
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The build method of the page is as follows:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // watch List
    List<Person> list = ref.watch(personProvider.select((value) => value.personList));
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.change_circle),
          onPressed: () {
            // modify the data of list 
            ref.read(personProvider).changeData();
          },
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: list
              .map((person) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(person.name),
                    subtitle: Text("${person.age}"),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ));
  }
```

[Code link](https://gist.github.com/liusilong/028b308b18b45ac9d23a531e6f098b24)

How to use flutter_riverpod to watch the data changes in the list, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Taking some liberty to change your code around just a bit; when working with Riverpod, I'll use `StateNotifier` over `ChangeNotifier` any day of the week. It allows, in my opinion, for more structured logic. Your code would look like this.

```
class PersonNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Person>> {
  PersonNotifier()
      : super([
          Person(name: "jack", age: 20),
          Person(name: "rose", age: 18),
        ]);

  void changeData(Person person) {
    state = [...state, person];
  }
}

final StateNotifierProvider<PersonNotifier, List<Person>> personProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider((ref) => PersonNotifier());
```

And you can then listen for your state in your code like this.

```
List<Person> list = ref.watch(personProvider);
```

Comment: The key is that the state has to change identity, in the form of `state = something` in your Notifier.